# Is there a way to preinstall ubuntu (so it shows the wizard to create an account, and orientation stuff, on first boot)?

Tags: preinstallation

Is there some toolkit used by the OEMs of Ubuntu to install Ubuntu in such a way that it displays some wizard to create an account, and maybe show an orientation video. Also, is there a way to preinstall some packages, also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at the [Ubuntu Customization Kit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/).

> Ubuntu Customization Kit is a tool that helps you customizing official
>   Ubuntu Live CDs (including Kubuntu/Xubuntu and Edubuntu) to your
>   needs. You can add any package to the live system, for example
>   language packs, or applications.<sup>1</sup>

To download see the [UCK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/) website.  For more information about customization, and other resources, see the [Live CD Customization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[UCK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/)</sup>